# Nmap is not sending ICMP timestamp requests when -PP flag is set

Tags: nmap, icmp

I'd like nmap to send ICMP timestamp requests to the host. To achieve this I use the command:

> nmap -PP "ip addr"

But among requests generated by nmap there are no ICMP requests, only TCP SYN packets.

The host is actually in my subnet. If I set "ip addr" to some non existing host from other subnet I observe ICMP timestamp requests.

So seems nmap sends ICMP timestamp requests only under special conditions.

What are these conditions?
And is it possible to force nmap to send ICMP timestamp requests to any host, maybe via some
additional flag?

As I know, there are other utils which can be used, like nping, hping3, but I'd like to first clarify the option with nmap.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [manual](https://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html):

> The `-P*` options (which select ping types) can be combined. You can
> increase your odds of penetrating strict firewalls by sending many
> probe types using different TCP ports/flags and ICMP codes. Also note
> that **ARP/Neighbor Discovery is done by default against targets on a
> local Ethernet network even if you specify other `-P*` options**, because
> it is almost always faster and more effective.

> The default host discovery done with `-sn` consists of an ICMP echo
> request, TCP SYN to port 443, TCP ACK to port 80, and an ICMP
> timestamp request by default. When executed by an unprivileged user,
> only SYN packets are sent (using a `connect` call) to ports 80 and 443
> on the target. **When a privileged user tries to scan targets on a local
> ethernet network, ARP requests are used unless `--send-ip` was
> specified.** The `-sn` option can be combined with any of the discovery
> probe types (the `-P*` options) for greater flexibility.

From these two parts one can guess that to force using ICMP timestamp this should be used (an ARP request will still be done by the OS if there's no such address in the ARP cache anyway!):

```
nmap --send-ip -PP lan.ip.addr.ess
```

To issue *only* such ICMP timestamp and do no reverse DNS lookup nor port scan:

```
nmap --send-ip -n -sn -PP lan.ip.addr.ess
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer!